# Powershell script to backup and replace files

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm working on project where deployment tool automatically adds the ".update" extension if same file already exists on destination.
e.g.

```
root
    web.config
    web.config.update
    connection.config
    connection.config.update
```

I would like to perform the following post-deploy via powershell:

1. Backup *.config.
2. Replace the existing *.config with *.update file.
   Below is the desired ouput:

   root
           web.config
           web.config.update
           connection.config
           connection.config.update
       root
           web.config 
           connection.config
           backup
               web.config
                   connection.config

Could someone please help how above could be achieved by using powershell?

Comment: and what is the question or the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code would perform what you want.

1. Backs up the existing config files to a backup folder named based on
   the current date.
2. Replace the existing config files by deleting them and renaming the update files.

   ```
   $root_folder = 'c:\temp\root'

   # Create a backup folder 
   $backup_directory = New-Item -Path "$root_folder\backup_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)" -Force -ItemType Directory

   Get-ChildItem -Filter *.config | ForEach-Object {

       # Copy .config files to the backup directory
       Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$($backup_directory.Fullname)" -Force

       # Delete the file from the source directory
       $_ | Remove-Item

       # Rename the .update files to .config files.
       Rename-Item -Path "$($_.FullName).update" -NewName $_.FullName -Force
   }
   ```

Comment: I wondered why your question got voted down. I guess you could re-phrase it to make it better:

1. I have the following requirements, etc.
2. How do I achieve this using Powershell?

Comment: Thank you, my bad I missed the last line on my copy paste from notepad++